# Execute Code On Standard Page Layout

Tags: lightning, page-layout

My goal is that whenever the Account page layout loads, custom code is executed. And, in order to execute the code properly I need to access the account object that is displayed on the Account page layout.

The functionality i am trying to add is that the Account object gets updated from a external source when the Account page layout loads.

I know I can add a custom lightning component and execute code on load, but is it possible to access the object loaded in the layout **from** the lightning component?

Currently I see any obvious functionality in the "Customize Page Layouts" section.

So I am expecting to be able to do something like

```
layout.load => {
Scope.object.field = 'new value' 
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the record id? depending on if you're using aura components or lwcs you can see these
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_record_context

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I just needed to access the record from the component. Take my newb upvote ↑